# r: assigning values to rasters with lapply

Tags: r, lapply, raster, assign

I'm trying to assign values to a number of raster files in a folder, and apply the `raster()` function to them, with the eventual aim to plot, stack, and subject algebra to them. So each raster file in the folder would be assigned to "r1", "r2" etc. So far I have:

```
f <- list.files(path="path/to/files", pattern="*.tif", full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE)

head(f)

[1] "path/to/files/wc2.1_2.5m_prec_1970-01.tif"    
[2] "path/to/files/wc2.1_2.5m_prec_1970-01.tif.ovr"
[3] "path/to/files/wc2.1_2.5m_prec_1970-02.tif"    
[4] "path/to/files/wc2.1_2.5m_prec_1970-02.tif.ovr"
[5] "path/to/files/wc2.1_2.5m_prec_1970-03.tif"    
[6] "path/to/files/wc2.1_2.5m_prec_1970-03.tif.ovr"

r <- lapply(f, raster)
lapply(r, function(i){
  assign(paste0("r", i), i)
})
```

However, if I return r1, it only gives the following output:

```
> r1
[1] 1
```

I'm not too sure how to ensure that r returns the actual raster rather than just an integer.

Comment: Hi nis38, it would be helpful if you can share the data that is returned when you `list.files` (or dummy data that is same shape and similar content) so we can cut and paste the code locally and reproduce your error. When we can run the code locally it is easier to explore for a solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is

```
f <- list.files(path="path/to/files", pattern="\\.tif$", full.names=TRUE)
library(raster)
s <- stack(f)
```

Now to your question: whatever you do, do **not** use `assign`. It is a common beginners mistake to think you need it. There are very few good uses of it --- and you will likely never need it. Using it leads to horrible code with many objects that you have call by name.

What you should do depends on what comes next and you did not tell us (but it is likely what I show above). Generally, if you want to use names, you could give names to the elements of the list

```
names(r) <- paste0("r", 1:length(r))
```

But this might be more helpful

```
names(r) <- gsub(".tif", "", basename(f))
```

If the layers have the same extent and resolution, make a RasterStack and name the layers (but you should really use `stack` on the filenames as I showed above)

```
s <- stack(r)
names(s) <- paste0("r", 1:nlayers(s))
```

Also, in list.files, you should be using `pattern="\\.tif$"` to not include the "*.ovr" files. The important part here is the `$` that says that the name should end on .tif. The `\\` means that you actually want a `.` and not use it as a wildcard (i.e. any character), which is what you are doing.

```
f <- list.files(path="path/to/files", pattern="\\.tif$", full.names=TRUE)
```